# PHP: Creating list of unique values using nested foreach loops

Tags: php, wordpress

Pretty sure my code is close to working, but I am having some difficulty. I'm using Wordpress, which has some functions in the first foreach loop to grab the pages that the current user authored, but I know that part works. My focus is on the second loop, which is intended to make an array comprised of unique values (page categories).

Have had trouble responding to users directly on here before (computer too old to update browser) so thanks ahead of time for the help!

```
$args= array('sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc', 'authors' => $current_user -> user_login;
    $pages = get_pages($args);
$uniques = array();
    foreach ($pages as $page) { 
$categories = get_the_category($page->ID);
    foreach ($uniques as $unique) {
        if ( in_array($categories[0]->name, $unique) )
        {
        continue;
        }
array_push($unique, $categories[0]->name);
echo end($unique[0]);
echo '<br>';
echo $categories[0]->name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your `foreach ($uniques as $unique) {` line. That loop will never execute since `$uniques` is always empty.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, thanks for your help!

```
$uniques = array ();

foreach ($pages as $page) {
$categories = get_the_category ($page->ID);

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    if ( ! in_array ($uniques, $category->name) ) {
        $uniques [] = $category->name;
    }
}

foreach ($uniques as $unique) {
    if (in_array ($categories [0]->name, $unique)) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I am getting correct that you wish to get all the unique values of categories in the array `$uniques` and `$categories[0]->name` is fetching the category name for you.

Then try using the `array_unique()` function of php then you might use `array_values()` to sort the indexes.

```
<?php 
$args= array('sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc', 'authors' => $current_user -> user_login;
$pages = get_pages($args);
$uniques = array();
foreach ($pages as $page) { 
    $categories = get_the_category($page->ID);
    $uniques[]  = $categories[0]->name;
}

$uniques_arr = array_unique($uniques);
print_r($uniques_arr);
$uniques_sorted = array_values($uniques);
print_r($uniques_sorted);
?>
```

This will get you only the first category from all the pages as we are only inserting 0 index. To get all the categories of all pages use below code

```
<?php 
$args= array('sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc', 'authors' => $current_user -> user_login;
$pages = get_pages($args);
$uniques = array();
foreach ($pages as $page) { 
    $categories = get_the_category($page->ID);
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $uniques[]  = $category->name;
    }
}

$uniques_arr = array_unique($uniques);
print_r($uniques_arr);
$uniques_sorted = array_values($uniques);
print_r($uniques_sorted);
?>
```